Issues with Pandas Dataframe Dtype when importing data from google worksheets
When importing a table from my google worksheet, the data type for my columns not inheriting the data types from my worksheet.
I have 14 columns containing text, float and dates.  Two of the columns correctly identify the Dtype as float64, however the remainder of the columns are assigned as object.
Some of my columns on my worksheet do contain empty value - source data.
I have tried to define the dtypes by passing them in when defining df, using df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=data_types), however this returns an TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
Any help with this would be much appreciated.

You should apply the format transformation after loading your dataframe.
I made this example and it works.
import pandas as pd

name = ['Olivia', 'Noah', 'James']
int_rate = ['5.16', '4.40', '4.40'] 
acc_open_date = ['12/01/2024', '', '']

data = {'Name':name,
        'Interest Rate': int_rate,
        'Account Open Date': acc_open_date
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Name'] = df['Name'].astype(str)
df['Interest Rate'] = df['Interest Rate'].astype(float)
df['Account Open Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Account Open Date'])

--
[In]  df.dtypes
[Out] Name                         object
      Interest Rate               float64
      Account Open Date    datetime64[ns]

